# Создание вложенных сериализаторов в Django

Tags: python, django

Не получается добавить поле с данными из другой модели.
Руководствовался: [этим](https://django.fun/docs/django-rest-framework/ru/3.12/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) и [этим](https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/content/glava-12-razrabotka-api/sozdanie-restful-api/sozdanie-vlozhennih-serializatorov.html)

Модели:

```
class Cards(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Имя карты')
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Номер карты')
    id_set = models.ForeignKey('Sets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ID сета')
    card_img = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class User_cards(models.Model):
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    id_cards = models.IntegerField()
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    foil = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    language = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default='01000000000')
```

Вьюха:

```
class CardsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CardSerializers
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = CardsFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        cardnames = Cards.objects.all()
        return cardnames
```

Серилизаторы:

```
class UserCardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User_cards
        fields = ('__all__',)

class CardSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_set = UserCardSerializers(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cards
        fields = ('name', 'user_set')
```

На выходе - просто поля модели Cards

Answer (score 0):

На выходе куда? Все выглядит нормально, только `__all__` должен быть простой строкой, а не кортежем, и непонятно куда ведет внешний ключ `id_set`. В связи "один ко многим" внешний ключ может быть только с одной стороны (у одной модели).
[image: корректное отображение вложенного сериалайзера в сваггере]

Comment: у меня он вот так отображает: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6-zCQfzOZEKskWfjTxG32ynLgTamLF7/view?usp=sharing . Не могу понять, что не так